# Ignoring Windows projects during compilation on non-Windows machines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

A solution has one C# project which targets net6.0-windows and uses Windows Forms and WPF libraries, the rest of the solution only targets net6.0. We need to make the solution compilable on multiple platforms and the net6.0-windows project is causing problems on non-Windows machines.

Is there a way to keep the Windows project in the solution and have it ignored when the solution is being compiled on non-Windows machines? The project does not need to be runnable on non-Windows machines, it should just not block the developers on such environments.

Comment: What problems are you having building the `net6.0-windows` project on Linux? Provided the .NET SDK is installed, cross-compilation should always _just work_ unless your WIndows-specific builds require things like COM Registration or so...

Comment: You were right. After talking to my Mac co-workers, it turned out we just needed to set one flag in the project configuration (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was missing in the Windows project configuration. After setting it, everything worked just fine:

```
<EnableWindowsTargeting>true</EnableWindowsTargeting>
```